# TCPF ImageSVG Not turning Text with writing-mode: tb. Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong or possible better PHP PDF libraries?

Tags: php, pdf, svg, tcpdf

I am trying to display SVGs into a PDF I am creating with TCPDF but the ImageSVG doesn't seem to support rotating text with "writing-mode: tb".  Is there an easy fix to this I'm missing?  Sample code below, the SVG file shows the text turned 90 degrees but the PDF print out shows it not rotated.

```
//test_temp.svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><svg width="550" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Write y title -->
<g class="yaxis_title">
    <text x="37.5" y="200" style="fill: #000000;  font-size: 9pt; text-anchor: middle; writing-mode: tb;">
        Count By Category
    </text>
</g>
</svg>
//end test_temp.svg


$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='test_temp.svg', $x=15, $y=30, $w='50', $h='50', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);
```

Comment: Maybe try non-deprecated values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: Robert Longson, thanks I will move away from the deprecated values.  Gave that a try, but still with writing-mode: vertical-lr; and vertical-rl it still prints horizontal-tb every time.

Comment: Maybe it's simply not supported then.